# Count attachments by SobjectType

Tags: soql, attachment

In a legacy org that is still using Attachments, I wanted to get a handle on how many Attachments there were per `SObjectType`.  How can I do that with SOQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit the [`Type` qualifier on the polymorphic `Parent` relationship](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys)

```
SELECT Count(Id), Parent.Type
    FROM Attachment
    GROUP BY Parent.Type
    ORDER BY Parent.Type
```

with results like

```
 21    Case
345    EmailMessage
...
```

This technique can thus be used on `Task.What` or `Task.Who` as in:

```
SELECT Count(Id), What.Type
    FROM Task
    GROUP BY What.Type
    ORDER BY What.Type

SELECT Count(Id), Who.Type
    FROM Task
    GROUP BY Who.Type
    ORDER BY Who.Type
```

The utility of these queries can help you locate where to spend your time on database hygiene (*cleaning out the stables as it were*)

The Type qualifier can be returned in non-aggregate query results:

```
SELECT ActivityDate, Who.Type, Who.Id
  FROM Task 
  WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
```

yielding

```
2021-04-16   Contact  003xxxxxxxxxxxx
2021-04-16   Contact  003yyyyyyyyyyyy
```